# custom toast in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toast

I have simple custom toast ,its work fine in class extents activity but in **fragments** i have a issue.
findviewbyid method dosn't work in fragments!!
how can i fix it?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoast, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
    ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText(message);

layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.imagetoast)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);



    Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
    mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
    mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    mytoast.show();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put your code under `onCreateView` method of the `Fragment` and then call `findViewById` method from view that fragment inflates, like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View parent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);

    View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoast,(ViewGroup)parent.findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
    ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText(message);

    layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.imagetoast)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);



    Toast mytoast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
    mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
    mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    mytoast.show();
    return parent;
}
```

Comment: nice answer but what if i have asyncktask..and in my asynctask i want to use custom toast..can you help me with this?

Comment: Is your AsyncTask inside a fragment?

Comment: You can't do anything after returning from function. If you want to show custom toast in 'onPostExecute()', 'onPreExecute()' methods, the answer will be the same, except that you should use 'getView()' method instead of inflating the 'parent'.

Comment: I am trying to add in doinbackgroundmethod..where I create runonuithread..and inside that runonuithread i want to use custom toast..

Comment: See this gist, I've created... https://gist.github.com/rom4ek/e7b8db27829d10c6b143

Comment: I've updated it with 'LayoutInflater.from()' method. Check it.

Comment: Id of your custom toast view.

Comment: still its showing reguler balck and white toast...and how can you use getBasecontext..its not allowing me..not getting option

Comment: You can use getActivity() instead of getBaseContext(). As for black and white toast - it's your view , you can change it in your xml.

Comment: I already change view and also getbasecontext to getactivity..yet thanks for answer i vote up...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and change layout and id accordingly:

```
LayoutInflater inflater1 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

View layout = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

// set a message
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Custom Toast");

// Toast...
Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```